# RequestLocationUpdates parameter android

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have confusion in this parameter

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 
                60000,
                10,
                listener);
```

So here is how it executes `location update listener`.
`if time = 60000 AND distance = 10` then it will execute or 
`if time = 60000 OR distance = 10` then it will execute.
Please help me to come out this confusion.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) :

> The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than `minTime`

So `minTime` takes precedence. Further on it says :

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed

So it should be `if(time >= minTime AND dist >= minDistance)`, meaning won't check distance if too early. BUT don't take those parameters too seriously [before JellyBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417753/281545).

Comment: "Jelly Beans" haha!  xD

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding it should be `OR`. Read [this blog](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/) for more info.

Keep in mind that GPS has an accuracy of 10 to 50 meters itself.

Comment: Not correct [anymore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score -1):

In this method second parameter 60000 show the time for update the of the location in millisecond so 60000 means 60 second (60*1000). 'OR'
The third parameter is the distance(minimum distance interval for update the location) in your case it is 10- mete

I hope this is help.

Comment: This is not help [anymore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)