# The locationListener is only invoked once

Tags: android, geolocation, android-asynctask, locationlistener

I want to send some data along with coordinates to a remote server each 10 seconds. I thought, that the best match would be the

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  //snip
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, new SendingLocationListener() );
}
```

in the listener I have the following code:

```
public void onLocationChanged( Location location ) {
  if( null == location ) return;
  TrackerNotifierTask task = new TrackerNotifierTask();
  task.execute( location );
}
```

the `TrackerNotifierTask` uses the `httpclient` in it's `doInBackground()` method, so it's pretty simple.

Now, if I start the activity, I can see that the `onLocationChanged()` gets executed and the data hits the remote server successfully. But only once! No matter what I do later, changing coords or anything, the task does not get called.

Is this the right way of implementing such thing in android or shall I resort to some `background-service`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772686/location-managers-requestlocationupdates-called-only-once).

It works as expected when `LocationListener` is implemented as an `anonymous class`.

Comment: ok, the trick with an anonymous inner class has worked, the listener is called upon each GPS (mock) update. On the other hand, the minTime seems to be ignored. Is it possible to force it somehow?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442093/how-do-i-decide-what-interval-to-use-for-requestlocationupdates, if it solves your problem.

Comment: I took a look at it... In my case I need to send a "keep-alive" signal to the server, even if the location didn't change - as long as the app is running. Maybe the vehicle stuck in a traffic jam or simply stopped, but the driver wants to receive status updates from the server. I could set-up a background service to "ping" a server, but then it would be a pain to keep those 2 processes from conflicting.

Comment: is it possible to "pimp" the locationManager to call listener.onLocationChanged() on a regular basis? in the javadoc stands: "The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation"

Answer (score 3):

the link from Shrikant gave me some hints on class-structure of the `LocationListener` implementation.

The class must not necessarily be defined as an `inner anonymous class`. I defined it as inner, but named one and it also worked.

The trick is, that the listener instance must be declared as a field:

```
private LocationListener listener;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  //snip
  locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
  listener = new MyLocationListener( SomeActivity.this );
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( provider, 1000, 0, listener );
}
```

Otherwise it will be garbage-collected after the 1st run, if defined like this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( provider, 1000, 0, new MyLocationListener() );
```

That was one half of the solution. The other part - about minTime - remains unresolved. Maybe it has something to do with emulator... I'll post the missing part as soon as I find the way.

UPDATE:
Seems like, that on a real device the minInterval seems to cause the listener to fire, no matter if the coords changed or not

Answer (score 0):

I'v a similar problem,
when I use

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener1 = new LocationListener() {
   @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       }
}
```

in my class, 
onLocationChanged is only invoked once,
but after I add "final" to

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener1 = new LocationListener() {
```

The problem is solved. (in my case, used by forground service)

It seems like
if  the variable is not defined with final keyword,
after it was called once , 
it would be garbage collected and will not be called again...